# How to eat raw chicken without getting salmonellosis?

Tags: food, avian, alcoholic-beverages

I imagined a French professional chef named Simon Charles. His favourite meat: chicken.

One day, he invents a new revolutionary recipe: chicken tartare.

So, I wonder how to eat raw chicken without getting salmonellosis. I believe putting absinthe and/or pastis would greatly reduce the risk.

Comment: Uh, the same way we eat raw eggs, or raw lettuce, or raw salmon? That is, by paying attention to the hygiene of the supply chain.

Comment: To add to what @AlexP said, salmonella in raw chicken pretty much caused by intensive livestock farming where they house tens of thousands chicken together; to mitigate the problems, the chicken are fed antibiotics that keep the salmonella bacteria dormant (because the drugs _no_ longer _kill_ the bacteria) so that the infection won't bother the industry.

Comment: I don't see how this is at all a Worldbuilding question and not one for [cooking.se]

Comment: Irradiate that meat with enough energy to break any remaining life inside, but with not enough energy to cause isotope generation. Alpha-radiation looks good for that. Ingesting helium won't do bad for a human, and if an amino acid molecule would get broken by a particle, so what, they already break within the body before being processed.

Comment: Here's a [recipe](https://www-cuisineaz-com.translate.goog/recettes/poulet-et-foie-de-volaille-en-tartare-de-grand-mere-36396.aspx?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=fr&_x_tr_pto=wapp) of chicken made like a tartare steak, excepted for the liver which is cooked in the pan. Point is, it's very real-worldy, and it looks like you could have used some more prior research ^^'. But perhaps you don't have access to as many cooking websites as in France ^^?

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing revolutionary in the recipe.

In Japan is possible to eat raw chicken sashimi, called [torihashi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torisashi)

> Torisashi is a Japanese dish of raw chicken breast sliced very thin. If the chicken is lightly seared it is known as toriwasa. It is most commonly eaten with sumiso but may also be eaten with soy sauce and wasabi like other sashimi.

[How can they eat it and not die](https://ajadeabroad.com/raw-chicken-in-japan/)?

> In the West, we are taught that uncooked chicken can only bring pain and misery… usually in the form of salmonella. However, in Japan, it is sometimes found in traditional Japanese restaurants, known as izakaya.
>
> No matter what you do, there is always a risk of getting food poisoning from chicken sashimi. However, the way you prepare the sashimi can reduce the chance of contracting something horrible.
>
> In Japan, the way they usually prepare the sashimi is by taking thin slices or cubes from the inner breast. This is the part of the chicken that has the lowest possibility of contamination.
>
> However, it’s not all sunshine and lollipops.
>
> In my cooking classes at school, I was only taught about salmonella being a possible enemy. But, it turns out salmonella isn’t our only smeg to fight off, here.
>
> One of Japan’s national newspapers, the Asahi Shimbun, declared that 60% of food poisoning from raw chicken in Japan was caused by the bacteria campylobacter. It’s found in the intestines of chickens, which is why chefs tend to avoid that area and stick to preparing sashimi from the inner breast.
>
> You should be aware that the outer breast gives rise to chances of contracting salmonella, though.